# Weak formulation and Lax-Milgram lemma for $\partial_t u = \partial_x (u^2 \partial_x u)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, parabolic-pde, coercive

Consider the PDE $$\partial_t u =  \partial_x (u^2 \partial_x u)$$ with some initial condition $u_0(x)$ and homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions for $x \in (0,1)$

I want to study existence and uniqueness of the solution via Lax-Milgram lemma: the **continuity** is not a problem, my concern is about **coercivity**.

More specifically, I need to show that the bilinear form $$a(u,v)=-(u^2 \partial_x u,\partial_x v)$$ is weakly coercive, i.e. there are $\lambda\geq0$ and $\alpha>0$  s.t. $$a(u,u) + \lambda ||u||_{L^2}^2 \geq \alpha ||u||_{H_0^1}^2$$

So I start with $a(u,u)=-\int_0^1 u^2 u_x^2dx $  but I don't know how to derive that inequality above. How should I move?

Comment: a is *not* bilinear! So even if you manage to prove coercivity, you cannot apply Lax-Milgram!